# Error when using MKMapView

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview

I created a single view application with story boards. All I had in my view was MKMapView, thats it. It compiles without errors or warning but when I run it, I get this error in my console window:

```
<Error>: ImageIO: CGImageReadSessionGetCachedImageBlockData ***   CGImageReadSessionGetCachedImageBlockData: readSession [0x8ab5750] has bad readRef [0x14b79c70]
```

I'm using Xcode 4.3 and iPhone Simulator 5.1. Any thoughts?

.h File

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h
#import CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h
#import MapKit/MapKit.h

@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>
{ 
IBOutlet MKMapView *worldView;
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
IBOutlet UITextField *locationTitleField;
}

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "WhereamiViewController.h"

@interface WhereamiViewController ()

@end

@implementation WhereamiViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code for your MapKitView?

Comment: The code does not have anything other than an Outlet for MKMapView in the header file.

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    
    IBOutlet MKMapView *worldView;
}

@end`

Comment: have you tried clearing the derived data? It seems this is a simulator error. Not necessarily with your code

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry I'm new to Xcode.

Comment: Go to `Organizer` (top right of xcode) select `Projects` then the project you're working on. Then click `Delete...` next to Derived Data.

Comment: Tried that, still getting the same error. It definitely something with the MKMapView because if I delete the MapView, I don't get that error.

Comment: AFAIK, mapkit shouldn't cause this error. From looking on the web it looks like it's related exclusively to images. Do you have any other code going on besides the mapkit?

Comment: Nope. I tried the same code on a different Mac and I still get the same error.

Comment: can you edit the original post to include both the .h and .m files? Maybe we can see if you're missing anything

Comment: Did you add the mapkit framework to the project?

Comment: Yes I added both MapKit and CoreLocation frameworks.

Comment: hmm are you sure you have no UIImageViews on the storyboard?

Comment: Positive! All I added was the MapView, TextField and the Activity Indicator. (screenshot added to the question).
I tried various combinations by created an empty project and then adding ViewControllers and Storyboard and still no luck.

Comment: I really have no idea, have you tried `Project`/ `Clean` ?

Comment: Yes, tried that as well. I guess I'm just going to let be and move forward. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's really bizarre. I would just try creating a new project. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Is this entire code you use? I got the same error, but it was when incorrectly adding coordinates to polyline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just ran into this:

Simple Fix: Make sure to check the box for "shows user location" for the MapView in interface builder.

Answer (score 3):

Probably i should not answer a question of almost a year, but i was having the same issue and the cause was that i was calling **CLLocationManager** **startUpdateLocation** on **viewDidLoad** method, when i change it to **viewWillAppear** the issue dissapeared.

Answer (score 2):

That looks to me like a bug in the framework. Report it using the [Apple Bug Reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com) and see if it's a known issue.

Answer (score 0):

My PNG's contained some transparent parts and I think this caused the problem, because after removing these parts the error disappeared. Maybe I had some error in my PNG files, because transparency should be supported.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem.  I solved it by commenting out all the code and compile the program.  Then I uncommented each method one by one compiling after each time.  For some reason that seemed to get rid of the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Correct ur codes as below, and create the outlet of map view.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I'm doing a much simpler project so I'm not sure if it will help you.  But I'll show you my code anyway.  You may want to just start with this and then see if you can build from there.

So for the ViewController.h it should read......

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit
```